# make inplace tag by default editable without click - primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, edit-in-place, inplace-editing

I am working with primefaces 4.0, I am wondering how to make the following inplace  tag editable without clicking the text here is the code

```
<p:inplace id="ajax" editor="true">
        <p:inputText value="#{inplaceView.text}" required="true" label="text" />
    </p:inplace>
```

so I must click the inplace to make it editable, I need to change this code to make it editable without any click or any action from the user once the page is loaded it should rendered as editable

Comment: Then **don't** use `p:inplace` around the `p:inputText` Or simply fake the onclicks when the page is loaded.... Al not too difficult

Comment: how can I fake the onclicks ?

Comment: via JavaScript... It is client-side all html and javascript. Stackoverflow has lots of Q/A on this

Comment: The problem is I have too many nested loops so I cant get the element id

Comment: FYI: There is an existing ticket about this https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1437 You can merge the associated PR to your code

Answer (score 0):

As Kukeltje stated you could fake clicks with JavaScript/jQuery. If you don't want to use the id you could make use of data-* attribute and select elements by that, for example:

```
<html ...
    xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

    <h:head>
        <title></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("[data-show-initial='true'] > span").click();
            });
        </script>

        <h:form id="form">
            <p:inplace id="inplace" editor="true" pt:data-show-initial="true">
                <p:inputText value="#{viewBean.value}" required="true" label="text" />
            </p:inplace>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Note that Pass Through Attributes (pt) only exist since JSF 2.2.

Comment: otherwise add a styleClass attribute

Comment: thanks I have used class instead as I am using jsf 2.0

Comment: I got another problem I have more than tab this script works fine on the first tab only any help please ?